# How do you monitor more 'standard' metrics with SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to visualize multiple metrics, while using only one as the objective.  I see how you can define 'custom' metrics using 'MetricDefinitions' under 'AlgorithmSpecification', but what if we just want to see more of the following and record them in CloudWatch as our HyperParameter tuning job progresses:

```
validation:accuracy 
validation:auc  
validation:error        
validation:logloss  
validation:mse
```

There are more, of course, and the exact metrics I realize might vary based on whether it's a classification or regression problem.

The larger question is just how do we specify the 'recording/logging' of more of these metrics using a standard container like the one for XGBoost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor a set of metrics for each problem type by using SageMaker Model Monitor[ [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-monitor-model-quality-metrics.html) ]
If you need to monitor any additional metrics apart from the default ones, you can use the [BYOC approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-monitor-byoc-containers.html) to monitor them.

Some of the examples for building BYOC can be found [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/detecting-data-drift-in-nlp-using-amazon-sagemaker-custom-model-monitor)